# Angular ngFor inline mode along with text on same line

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I am using https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs
For flex layouts in angular

I want to display items in inline mode

Eg: for 3 items should be like this text should break to new row if it is very long

item 1, item 2, item 3 this is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long textthis is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long text
[image]
Eg: for 2 items should be like this text should break to new row if it is very long

item 1, item 2 this is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long textthis is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long text

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap"
         fxLayoutGap="10">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"
             fxFlex="25">
            <child-component>
            </child-component>
            <span *ngIf="items.length !== i + 1 && items.length!== 1">,&nbsp;</span>
            <span *ngIf="items.length === i + 1"> this is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long text
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

My problem is if the text is very long it always display on next line
SHould display within the line

[image]

Comment: please share a screenshot of how it looks now and how you want it to look! also if possible the contents of `child component`, `items` and `the css used`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from overflowing to tbe next line. Please share back the provided stackblitz with the issue reproducible for debugging!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div fxLayout="row wrap"
         fxLayoutGap="10">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"
             fxFlex="25">
            <child-component>
            </child-component>
            <span *ngIf="items.length !== i + 1 && items.length!== 1">,&nbsp;</span>
            <span *ngIf="items.length === i + 1" 
                  style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap;display: flex;"> 
                       this is a very long text this is a very long textthis is a very long text
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-flex-layout-example-hjnebt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcard.component.html)

Comment: sorry above final image result in my question  is what i was expecting
to break the word if text is long

Comment: @BUlle7 could you update the stackblitz and share back with the issue occuring and share it back to me,it would help me a lot

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-flex-layout-example-kuy2xd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
something like this